# find diagonal in 2 dimensional array

Tags: c#, c++, c, builder

I have a 2-dimensional array with user-entered values. I need to find sum of the even elements in the diagonal of the array.

I know how to declare the array and get it filled by the user, but I'm not sure what **even elements in the main diagonal** really means.

I know I can find out if a number is even by saying:

```
if  n / 2 == 0
```

Once I've reported the sum of the even elements in the diagonal, I would like to replace all 0 values in the array with ones.

Comment: You confirm there actually is a main diagonal (that is, your 2 dimensional array represents a valid square matrix). Then you look at each element in the main diagonal and check if it's even. and you replace all 0's by 1 by replacing all 0's by 1. You really can't break this down much further, you should look into your notes again (besides, it's not even clear what language you are talking about).

Answer (score 3):

Diagonal means all places where x and y cordinates are the same
Do if your array contains:

**1** 3 8 5
3 **3** 9 7
4 4 **5** 7
5 1 7 **4**

Then the diagonal are in bold.

Comment: thanks alot I am do the coding part but to be sure a bout what is the meaning of Diagonal and you telk me so that thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the array is a square:

```
int sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < numOfArrayRows; i++)
{
    //Use the mod operator to find if the value is even.
    if(array[i][i] % 2 == 0)
        sum += array[i][i];

    //Change 0's to ones
    for(int j = 0; j < numOfArrayCols; j++)
        if(array[i][j] == 0)
            array[i][j] = 1;
}
```

Also, next time add the "Homework" tag if you have a homework question :P

Comment: LOL
Well said Super :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework - however I will help out :)

So if you have an 2D array, and in order to find the sum of the diagonal values, you will know that the indices of both of the values would match in order to provide you with each of the diagonal values.

**To iterate through these you could use a simple loop that would sum up every diagonal value, as shown:**

```
//Your Sum
int sum = 0;

//This will iterate and grab all of the diagonals
//You don't need to iterate through every element as you only need
//the diagonals.
for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
{
   //This will add the value of the first, second, ... diagonal value to your sum
   sum += array[i,i];
}
```

**To set each of the values that is 0 to 1, you could iterate through each element of the array and check if the value is 0, then set that value to 1, for example:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeOfArray; j++)
    {
         //Check if this value is 0;

         //If it is 0, set it to 1, otherwise continue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a two-dimensional array it's really easy, since you don't need any index magic:

```
int a[N][N] = ...;
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
    if(a[i][i] % 2 == 0) //or a[i] & 1, if you like, just check if it's dividable by 2
        sum += a[i][i];
```

This C++ code shouldn't be that different in C or C#, but you should get the point. Likewise the second question would be as simple as:

```
int a[M][N] = ...;
for(i=0; i<M; ++i)
    for(j=0; j<N; ++j)
        if(a[i][j] == 0)
            a[i][j] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

And I suspec that the main diagonal is the one that begins with coordinates 0,0.

To replace 0 elements with 1 you would do something like:

if (array[i,j] == 0) array[i,j] == 1;

Answer (score 0):

```
int[,] array = new int[,] {{1,2,3},
                           {4,5,6},
                           {7,8,9}};
    //Suppose you want to find 2,5,8
    for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
       for(int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
       {
          if((row == 0 && column == 1) || (row == 1 && column == 1) || (row == 2 && column == 1))
          {
             Console.WriteLine("Row: {0} Column: {1} Value: {2}",row + 1, column + 1, array[row, column]);
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need, not much explain:

```
            //Read the size of the array, you can get it from .Count() if you wish
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[][] a = new int[n][];
        //Reading all the values and preparing the array (a)
        for (int a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++)
        {
            string[] a_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            a[a_i] = Array.ConvertAll(a_temp, Int32.Parse);
        }
        //performing the operation (google what diagonal matrix means)
        int PrimarySum = 0, SecondarySum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            //The If condition is to skip the odd numbers
            if (a[i][i] % 2 == 0) { PrimarySum += a[i][i]; }
            //For the reverse order
            int lastelement = a[i].Count() - 1 - i;
            if (a[i][lastelement] % 2 == 0) { SecondarySum += a[i][lastelement]; }
        }
        //Get the absolute value
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Abs(PrimarySum - SecondarySum).ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using C#, I would make like this:

```
int[,] matrix = new int[4, 4];

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++) {
        if (matrix[i, i] == matrix[j, j]) { 
            matrix[i, j] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            matrix[i, j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```